# update image is not working in django rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am learning DRF. I have one table called UserProfile. I'm trying to update profile image of user but in profile_image column updating only name of the image and newly added image not showing in media folder.

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name= models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    profile_img= models.ImageField(upload_to="Profile_Images", blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def put(self, request):
        data = request.data

        user_profile= UserProfile.objects.filter(id=data.get('id')).update(first_name=data.get('first_name'), last_name= data.get('last_name'), email= data.get('email'), profile_img= request.data['profile_img'])

        response = {"result":'User Profile Updated'}
        return Response(response)
```

when i create new user its working fine and profile image stored in media/Profile_Images folder(in db it's stored like Profile_Images/xyz.jpg inside profile_img column). when i update existing user profile other fields are updating but profile_img field is not updating(when i update profile_img in db its showing like abc.jpg and it is not showing in media/Profile_Images folder). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are getting from form-data so you have to use request.FILES to get files

```
def put(self, request):
        data = request.data
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
        profile_image = request.FILES["profile_img"]
        user.first_name=data.get('first_name')
        user.last_name= data.get('last_name')
        user.email= data.get('email')
        user.profile_img= profile_image
        user.save()
        response = {"result":'User Profile Updated'}
        return Response(response)
```

Comment: It's Working. Thanks a lot.